# How to manage multiple small parts of a library with version control

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I'm new to source version control, so I don't want to make a mistake in choosing the wrong setup for my project.
I have kind of a "library" that is made of many small "procedures" (they are written in a pseudo-language specific of a third paty software). Each procedure is a small stand alone "package" of 2/3 files (just the procedure itself, the documentation, and maybe one or two other sub-procedures that are needed only to the main one).

So I have like hundreds of those procedure-packages, archived in subfolders depending on the area of application, and some of them more complex may use others more basic.

I modify those procedures pretty often in the early stages, to improve them, but of course sometimes the modifications break the compatibility since thei involve adding/removing input/output parameters, so I suppose I must somehow "tag" versions of each procedure as if it was a single piece of software...

So I'm wondering what's the best way to manage them with a version control (I'm using Mercurial): am I supposed to make like hundreds repositories? o_O Or keep everything in one big repository and tag it everytime a procedure is revised? or maybe learn and use subrepositories?

Thanks for your help.

Simone

Answer (score 0):

I *can be* subrepositories (or [GuestRepo](https://bitbucket.org/selinc/guestrepo) - no updates from 2013) with tags

1. Each changeset in "main" repo have linked to it changesets from all repositories, i.e. when you update to old changeset in master, all subrepos also updated accordinly
2. Tags in main repository will allow you to mark stable|functional combinations for re-use

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure if I should start implementing subrepositories... it's marked as "a feature of last resort." in the documentation :-/

Comment: It's a feature that works well. It's marked as 'last resort' because it adds a lot of complexity.

I would argue that it's probably best to stick with a single repository for simplicity, and work out some kind of 'tagging scheme' to make good tags for your procedures. It'll be a lot less complicated than involving subrepos.

Answer (score 0):

Subrepos make sense, if each package can stand for itself without any connection to the master software. If this condition is not met, I would stay with one single repository. Especially since you stated that your packages contain few files with few changes it seems that the subrepo approach does not make sense here.

Comment: Well, as I said the main project itself is this "collection" of procedures. There are some basic procedures that do not depend on anything, but some others more structured that make use of one or more basic procedures. I've read a great explanation of subrepos on the foggcreek Klin website, and I like the idea of being able to change the signature of a procedure without breaking the others that make use of it until I explicitly pull the new version. While making one single repository for each procedure looks like really a nonsense now, because of the administration overhead for example...

Comment: I would go for the one-repository-approach for two reasons: a) You say stuff is (partially) dependent on eachother. As such keeping them in sync seems useful as you do not want to use several versions of a *single* procedure concurrently most likely. That situation might easily arise, though, if you use specific versions for different procedures. b) It's easy to change to the sub-repository approach later on if the one-repository approach does not suit you after all. The other way around is much more stony and sub-repositories definitely have their rough edges.